# Tools / Addons to debug a slow web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

what tools do you use to find the cause of a slow web page caused by poor use of HTML/CSS/JS?

We are eliminating the backed (php, server, dns, etc.) and purely focused on browser parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to try and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Page Speed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/) can help you a lot.